# Javascript Promises-Dynamic Callbacks

Tags: javascript, promise

I was reading this article on promises http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ In which he mentions the following point
***"If a promise has succeeded or failed and you later add a success/failure callback, the correct callback will be called, even though the event took place earlier"***

I'm not clear about this point. My Question here is,if a promise had already succeeded and later at some point if i add a callback ,how can this callback execute even though the event took place earlier

Please explain

Thanks
Sahithi

Comment: Can you fix the link? It's throwing a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: Are you talking about this link http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises

Comment: When you add the callback, it gets automagically added to the callback queue immediately if the promise is already resolved. What is there to explain?

Comment: Any Sample Code will be really help ful...because how can i set the callback after promise is resolved

Comment: @user3519495, the same way you would set it if it hasn't been resolved. Did you know `Promise.resolve()` returns an already resolved promise? So `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("hi"));` is doing what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The promise knows whether it was resolved or rejected. So if you attach another event handler to it, it will call it appropriately.

For example:

```
function myFunc(){ return Promise.resolve();}

var myPromise = myFunc();
myPromise.then(function(){console.log('I resolved.');});
myPromise.then(function(){console.log('Me too!');});
```

Would result in:
I resolved.
Me too!

Comment: Consider an Event listener is added after an event is fired ,if the event is not fired again ,this event listener would not be called again.If an action to promise is set after it is resolved,it  will execute.Compare this to the event listener ,event listener would never get called if the event is already fired.This is what i got the difference between event vs promises... so in the above example as myFunc is already resolved but an action is set at a later time so it is displaying as :"I resolved Me too" ...Is my understanding correct

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.then()` on a promise, it has one of three possible things to do depending upon whether the promise is already resolved, rejected or still pending.

1. If the promise is currently pending (not resolved or rejected), it can queue the passed-in `.then()` handlers for later use when the promise is actually resolved or rejected.
2. It can see that the promise is already resolved so it can schedule the resolveHandler that was passed in to run as soon as the stack unwinds
3. It can see that the promise is already rejected so it can schedule the rejectHandler that was passed in to run as soon as the stack unwinds

Imagine this pseudo code to illustrate:

```
Promise.prototype.then = function(resolveHandler, rejectHandler) {
    var self = this;
    if (this._promiseState === "pending") {
        // promise is not yet resolved or rejected so 
        //     just queue the .then handlers for later use
        this._handlers.push({resolve: resolvehandler, reject: rejectHandler});
    } else if (this._promiseState === "resolved") {
        // already resolved, schedule the resolve handler to run 
        //    immediately after stack unwinds
        if (resolveHandler) {
            setImmediate(function() {
                var p  = resolveHandler(self._resolvedValue);
                // further processing
            });
        }
    } else {
        // already rejected, schedule the reject handler to run
        // immediately after stack unwindws
        if (rejectHandler) {
            setImmediate(function() {
                var p  = rejectHandler(self._rejectReason);
                // further processing
            });
        }
    }
    // more code here that eventually returns a new promise

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, this basically means that you can run a promise and after running it, set the callback.

In event-oriented programming, you must first set the event callback, otherwise if triggered it'll never do the proper callback.

With promises, you can run a promise `someFunc()` and later add the callbacks, regardless of when the promise is fulfilled in runtime.

Comment: How do we add the `callback` later ? Any sample code will be helpful! What will happen if I add `resolve` handler in `setTimeout` but promise is fulfilled earlier ?

Comment: @KevinB, No man! But this is what came in my mind when I read this question. I hope you will not mind answering it.. May help others.. ;)